# Is it possible to show EmptyView after loader(ActivityIndicator) in CarouselView using Xamarin forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I have a lot of tried to show EmptyView after Loader but did not get success might i missed some code configuration for the EmptyView and Loader.

I'm using ActivityIndicator loader for the loading view if it will hide once data will come.

**Below code is for EmptyView for the CarouselView**

```
<CarouselView.EmptyView>
                <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="20,150">
                <Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="20" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Data not Found" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </Frame>
            </Frame>
    </CarouselView.EmptyView>
```

**Below code is for ActivityIndicator**

```
<StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" Padding="12" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">
    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color="#BFA464" x:Name="PaymentLoader"/>
    <Label Text="Data is Loading..." HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="#BFA464"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**Below image is my whole code screenshot**

[here is full code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsRy8.png)

If anybody have idea, please share your great and valuable knowledge.

Comment: Maybe you can try <CarouselView IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" with BoolConverter
https://www.xamarinexpert.it/how-to-invert-a-boolean-value/

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and code, I guess that you want to display CarouselView's EmptyView and ActivityIndicator when no data found, am I right?

From [Xamarin.Forms CarouselView EmptyView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/emptyview), we can see that EmptyView, of type object, the string, binding, or view that will be displayed when the ItemsSource property is null, or when the collection specified by the ItemsSource property is null or empty. The default value is null.

I do one sample that you can take a look:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!--  Place new controls here  -->
    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding models}">
        <CarouselView.EmptyView>
            <Frame Margin="20,150" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    CornerRadius="20"
                    HeightRequest="150"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="300">
                    <Label
                        FontSize="Medium"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Text="Data not Found"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </Frame>
            </Frame>
        </CarouselView.EmptyView>
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame
                        Margin="8"
                        BorderColor="Gray"
                        CornerRadius="20"
                        HasShadow="True"
                        HeightRequest="250"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        WidthRequest="300">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                            <Label
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="24"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>

    <StackLayout
        Padding="12"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <ActivityIndicator
            x:Name="PaymentLoader"
            IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
            Color="#BFA464" />
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="Data is Loading..."
            TextColor="#BFA464" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<BirdsModel> models { get; set; }
    private Boolean _IsBusy;
    public Boolean IsBusy
    {
        get { return _IsBusy; }
        set
        {
            _IsBusy = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsBusy");
        }
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsBusy = true;
        models = new ObservableCollection<BirdsModel>();        
        this.BindingContext = this;          
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        await Task.Delay(2000);

        models.Add(new BirdsModel() { Title = "title 1", ImagePath = "a5.jpg" });
        models.Add(new BirdsModel() { Title = "title 2", ImagePath = "a6.jpg" });
        models.Add(new BirdsModel() { Title = "title 3", ImagePath = "a7.jpg" });
        models.Add(new BirdsModel() { Title = "title 4", ImagePath = "a8.jpg" });

        IsBusy = false;

    }
}

public class BirdsModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ImageSource ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

This is the sample at github, you can take a look:

https://github.com/CherryBu/CarouselViewSample